# A bible for local and global unitary groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, reductive-groups

I am seeking a self-sufficient and quite comprehensive references in order to grasp the unitary groups. More precisely, I would like to have clearly exposed:

- their definition and construction
- what can happen at local places
- their properties as reductive groups
- the relations between local and global groups
- the classification (Witt decomposition for instance)